# Force application to run in Restore Down mode in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When I execute my application it runs in full screen. Do I have a way to run it in minized window or restore down mode?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is “restore down mode”?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a shortcut of the application. Then right-click the shortcut > Properties. Now in Shortcut tab, set Run dropdown to Minimized. Now launch the application always using that shortcut.

Comment: I'll try this and will get back to you and upvote if this works. Thanks!